# Can anyone suggest a voltmeter that can do the job?

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement

I am trying to make a high voltage measurement on an industrial sputtering machine.  The voltages are in the 50V to 1000V range.  Right now, we're using a Fluke DMM because we need a true floating voltage measurement (there's a lot of random common-mode noise that can't be eliminated).  It works great, but it is battery powered and doesn't have any computer output capability.

We'd really like to replicate this function with a powered meter that can talk to a computer, so the data can be automatically logged.  I've read a lot about this (although I still understand little).  I understand that, in order to get a good floating, differential measurement, the meter must be well electrically isolated from our chassis with all the common mode noise and also from its own power signal.

If I could find something that could make this measurement and scale it to, say, a 0-10V output, I would be enthralled.  Any suggestions or educations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wanted to follow up.

I've finally found a device that can do this job.  I just wanted to post in case anyone happens upon this thread, searching for the same thing:

[APD HV-DC High Voltage DC to DC Transmitters, Isolated, Field Rangeable](http://api-usa.com/pdf/api/apdhvdc.pdf)

which is made by [API-USA](http://api-usa.com/).

Answer (score 2):

46Fluke (US), Multimeters, select a multimeter
Then 1000 V 
USB thumb drive logging gives the 8846A
With USB interface 789, 289, 287 are possibilities.  What EN61010-1 CAT do you need?

Comment: I tried to edit a typo, but couldn't because of the length restriction.  Anyhow, the product is **8846A**, not 8864A.